# TextOut add margins to background

Tags: c++, winapi, text-editor

I an writing my text box control, and i try to make selection, that the selected text will be shown with Light blue background, then I noticed that the background surf sometimes over other letters, So I checked it out, as you will see in the following example, and I found that the `TextOut` function adds margins to background.

this is the example code:

global variables:

```
int WritePosition = 0;
bool color;
```

and the code:

```
case WM_CHAR:

    hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
    SetMapMode(hdc, MM_HIMETRIC);

    wchar_t wch;
    wch = (wchar_t)wParam;

    SIZE size;
    GetTextExtentPoint32(hdc, &wch, 1, &size);

    if(color)
        SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(190, 210, 236));
    color = !color;

    TextOut(hdc, WritePosition, 0, &wch, 1);

    WritePosition += size.cx;
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
```

this code write the letters, one with white background, and one with Light blue background, and so on.

[image]

as you can see in the output images, the background of second letter, Covered by the background of the third letter.
Is there a way to prevent the addition of background?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. The bottom image looks *correct* to me—that's exactly what I would *want* to see happen when I tried to set the background of the character in the middle. What were you hoping would happen differently? Anyway, if you don't want a background to be painted, make the background transparent.

Comment: It's caused by kerning.  Character cells are larger than the character itself, and kerning can cause cells to overlap.  Since the cell is what gets painted with the background color, there can be visible overlap.  As @CodyGray said, if you don't want that happening, use a transparent background color.  You could also use a monospaced font to eliminate the kerning.

Comment: See this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091835/in-win7-some-fonts-dont-work-like-they-did-in-win2k-xp/15102181#15102181  Apparently, TextOut fudges with width of the background area when ClearType is enabled.

Comment: @Cody Gray - I mean the area of a character cell, enters into the area of another character cell. as you see in the first image the background of the second character continues on the right side about 3 pixels after the letter, and in the second image you can see that the background of the third character deletes about two pixels from the background of the second character. --- and I don't want make the background transparent, because I want to display background for the selected text.